# Yii2 Changes user's password automatically

Tags: yii2

I have a model named `user`. This model has `password`, `media_id` and many other properties.

I want to change a single property using this method:

```
$user = User::find()
            ->where([
                "id" => $id
            ])
            ->one();
        $user->media_id = null;
        if($user->save()){
            return [
                "ok" => true
            ];
        }
        else{
            return [
                "ok" => false,
                "result" => $user->errors
            ];
        }
```

But when I run this code, the password field will change to an unknown value so the user can't log in anymore.

But when I use the following method:

```
User::updateAll([
            "media_id" => null
        ],
            [
                "id" => $id
            ]);
```

My query works properly. What is the problem with first code?

UPDATE1:

This is the rule:

```
public function rules() {
        return [
                ['password', 'required', 'message' => 'لطفا کلمه عبور خود را وارد نمایید', 'on' => 'register'],
                ['email', 'required', 'message' => 'لطفا ایمیل خود را وارد نمایید', 'on' => 'register'],
                ['email', 'duplicateEmail', 'message' => 'لطفا ایمیل خود را وارد نمایید', 'on' => 'register'],
                ['email', 'validateRegisterEmail', 'message' => 'لطفا ایمیل خود را وارد نمایید', 'on' => 'register'],
                ['email', 'required', 'message' => 'لطفا ایمیل خود را وارد نمایید', 'on' => 'changeEmail'],
                ['email', 'duplicateEmail', 'message' => 'لطفا ایمیل خود را وارد نمایید', 'on' => 'changeEmail'],
                ['email', 'validateRegisterEmail', 'message' => 'لطفا ایمیل خود را وارد نمایید', 'on' => 'changeEmail'],
//            [['code', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'mobile', 'email', 'password', 'bio', 'degree', 'favorites', 'type', 'active', 'active_mobile', 'active_email', 'modified_password', 'created', 'modified', 'deleted'], 'required'],
                [['gender', 'media_id', 'cover_media_id', 'type', 'active', 'active_mobile', 'active_email', 'deleted'], 'integer'],
                [['degree', 'bio', 'favorites'], 'string'],
                [['modified_password', 'created', 'modified'], 'safe'],
                [['code'], 'string', 'max' => 10],
                [['forget_password_token'], 'string', 'max' => 32],
                [['first_name', 'last_name', 'email'], 'string', 'max' => 50, 'message' => 'تعداد کاراکتر بیش از حد مجاز می باشد'],
                [['mobile'], 'string', 'max' => 12, 'message' => 'تعداد کاراکتر بیش از حد مجاز می باشد'],
                [['password'], 'string', 'max' => 20, 'message' => 'تعداد کاراکتر بیش از حد مجاز می باشد', 'on' => 'register'],
                [['media_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Media::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['media_id' => 'id']],
                [['cover_media_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Media::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['cover_media_id' => 'id']],
                ['type', 'default', 'value' => 1],
                ['type', 'in', 'range' => [self::ROLE_USER, self::ROLE_INSTRUCTOR, self::ROLE_AUTHOR, self::ROLE_MANAGER, self::ROLE_INVESTOR]],
        ];
    }
```

I have tested `save(false)` but still password changes.

I also tested `model.validate()` and password didn't change.

password changes just when I run `model.save()`.

This is my [model](https://gist.github.com/Alavi1412/d9144db1d82dca0c3c08f9ec6b552a55)

Comment: You probably have some weird magic in validation rules or `beforeSave()`.

Comment: Use save function without validation, like  $user->save(false)

Comment: Add the `rules()` from your `User` model .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> public function beforeSave($insert) {
>   if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
>       // Place your custom code here
>       if (!$this->notChangePassword)
>           $this->setPassword($this->password);
>       return true;
>   }
> }
> ```

This is the reason. `$notChangePassword` is `null` be default, so `$this->setPassword($this->password)` will be called on every `save()` (and hash already hashed password).

I suggest to not use the same attribute for raw and hashed password. You may introduce `$rawPassword` property and use it in forms instead for `$password`.

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface {

    public $rawPassword;

    public function beforeSave($insert) {
        if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
            if (!empty($this->rawPassword)) {
                $this->setPassword($this->rawPassword);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: What will happen if I remove the internal `if`?